# Files not uploading despite not reaching the file size limit

Tags: php, file-upload

I set up a simple PHP script for uploading files. Here it is:

**index.php**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="myfile"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
  $dir = "uploads/";
  $file = $dir . basename($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"], $file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
?>
```

All files, together with the uploads folder, are in one directory.

I also set a limit for the file size by amending this line in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1G
```

Despite modifying php.ini to allow files up to a size of 1GB, I cannot even upload a 10MB file. When submitting, I get three errors:

> **Warning:** POST Content-Length of 10935316 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
>    **Notice:** Undefined index: myfile in C:\WampServer64\www\fileupload\upload.php on line 3
>   **Notice:** Undefined index: myfile in C:\WampServer64\www\fileupload\upload.php on line 5

Other smaller files (8MB) upload normally.

Where is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is related to `POST` data in general (which uploads go through), and is not specific to file uploads.

The PHP setting you're looking for is [`post-max-size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size). You should be able to fix your issue by increasing its value.

Relevant part from the docs:

> Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file
>   upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than
>   upload_max_filesize.

Comment: Thanks. I set it to 1G, however, I am still getting the last two errors.

Comment: Nevermind. You say "larger than upload_max_filesize". I worked, thanks again!

Comment: @WaisKamal You're welcome. You can also mark the answer as accepted if you'd like. Have a good one.

Comment: Sure. It will only let me do so after some time.